# Escape hanging jQuery on load?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, async-await

If I'm using a jQuery on load to wait for everything to load, e.g.:

`$(window).on('load', ()=>{$('.content').show();}`

If it hangs on loading something for a really long time for whatever reason, is there way to execute the callback anyway?

`$(window).on('load', ()=>{$('.content').show();} // unless it takes a really long time, then show the content anyway`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially set a timer (define how much "too long" is) and call it if it hasn't been called by window 'onload' yet. You would need to unbind it to make sure it doesn't get called twice (although if it's `show` specifically you're triggering, then it won't matter because it doesn't 'reshow').

```
let hasbeencalled = false;

$(window).on('load', showContent);

window.setTimeout(() => {
    if(!hasbeencalled) {
        showContent();
        // Optionally unbind the load event:
        $(window).unbind('load');
    }
}, 300);


function showContent() {
    hasbeencalled = true;
    $('.content').show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This totally works... I was just wondering if jQuery had some built-in error handling for on load, like ajax `$.get().done().fail()`